# Downloading files and asking for storge permission in android

Tags: java, android

In my android app. When someone tries to download file, it should ask for storage permission.. if granted, it should start downloading the file.
Next time if permission already granted, just start new download.
here is the part of my code...

```
        public void downloadFile(String url) {
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);

            // Make a new request pointing to the download url
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

            String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
            String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, fileExtension);

            // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.contains("?dl=1")) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    downloadFile(url);
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                }
                return true;

            }
```

The problem with this code is:

When user deny the permission app crashes.

When user allow the permission for the first, time the download doesn't start immediately... user need to click again on the download link.

Comment: **It's not perfect** is not a question that can be answered. Mention the error/non required behavior along with the logcat if it's there.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out for Permission asking: developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @baalal have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the callback function `ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`.

So first step is to change your class signature to something like this but be careful to extend the Activity that you need the permission results in, `MainActivity` is just an example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
```

Second step is to override the following function:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            int[] grantResults) {

   if( requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
   {
       if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
             //Do something if the permission is granted
       }
       else
       {
             //Do something if the permission denied
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Check this out for Permission asking: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @RameshKumar what should I check?

Answer (score 0):

Your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method always returns `true`. Is that the wanted behavior?

Try to add a permission request response code as below:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], 
                                          int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // do your work
            } else {
                // permission denied
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request